# What is the url for page-test.php?

Tags: wordpress

I create a file page-test.php in my template directory.
page-test.php

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

What is the url for this page?

But it's not working...

i want to find the url for display the php file "page-test.php"

Comment: Have you created a custom template?

Comment: Sorry i don't put the file in "template directory but in my "theme directory".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this line to create the page template in WordPress

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

and then write your code in this PHP file

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

After that, assign this page template to the admin area,

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

I hope it might be helpful to you!

Comment: Is it possible to just display the file with <?php echo "Hello"; ?> without using template?

Comment: Yes, Take your home URL, 
after that URL just join your file name. 

for example www.yourwebsite.com/page-test.php 

Please try this. Because you have put your file in your template directory. 
So if it's on the root directory It will be work as this example.